# How do you stop a creeper from exploding via commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have built a structure in creative mode that is filled with creepers. The problem is I want to go to survival mode without blowing up the structure or myself. I don't know anything about commands about summoning and stuff like that. The only command I know is `give_[player]_a_[something]`. So, how do I summon creepers that will ( or if possible make the creepers that I already have ) not be able to explode?

Comment: Which edition of Minecraft are you playing?

Comment: I'm not really sure, but I play on a phone.

Comment: Minecraft on mobile is Bedrock edition. @Bloonchipper Please avoid accepting edits that introduce a new tag if you yourself said you don't know which tag to use.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123031/discussion-on-question-by-bloonchipper-how-do-you-stop-a-creeper-from-exploding).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is just to not provoke the creepers. Since you don't want them to break anything, you could go into the settings for your world and turn off the button that says "Mob Griefing". This will allow you to make sure that no mobs can affect blocks, thus, making sure that your creepers will not cause any damage when exploding.